# Calculate difference between months in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot, looker-studio

I'm using Big Query and Data Studio to build a query for a pivoted sum over months, like:

```
> Name|Jan|Feb|Mar|...
> abc |123|234|676|...
> SUM |123|234|676|..
```

But what I need now is a difference between two months :

```
> Name|Jan|Feb |Mar |...
> abc |123| 234| 676|...
> SUM |123| 234| 676|..
> Diff|0  |+111|+442|..
```

How can achieve this the best and most efficient way?

Comment: Can you show us data where the numbers actually make sense?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen at some point they do. I believe diff is calculated by substracting previous month sum from current month that we're looking at. What is abc column for, though, I can't to figure out.

Comment: Yeah, sorry maybe the example was not the best work. abc is nothing more like a text column. And yes diff would be the difference between the months

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a basic airthmetic:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select name, jan, feb, mar, . . .
from t
union all
select concat(name, '-DIFF'), 0, feb - jan, mar - feb, . . . 
from t;
```